# rsync remote to local automatic backup

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

Because all my work is stored on a remote server I would like to auto backup my server monthly and weekly. My server is running Centos 5.5 and while searching the web I'm found a tool named rsync. I got my first update manually by using this command in terminal:

```
sudo rsync -chavzP --stats USERNAME@IPADDRES: PATH_TO_BACKUP LOCAL_PATH_TO_BACKUP
```

I then prompt my password for that user and bob's my uncle.

This backups the necessary files from my remote server to my local device but does somebody know how I can automate this? Like automatic running this script every sunday?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I let direct admin backup the files I need and then copy those files from the remote server to a local server.

Comment: That's what cron is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you backup from the remote server to a local machine that is always up and reachable.

First set up public key authentication with your server. In your remote server do

```
~# ssh-keygen
```

accept the default and don't type the any password, so that the key will work passwordless. Then do

```
~# ssh-copy-id user@yourlocalmachine.example.com
```

and give the local server user password. Test it with:

```
~# ssh user@yourlocalmachine.example.com
```

You should log in passwordless.

After that, in  your remote server, add a cron job executing the appropriate rsync commands. For example:

```
~# vim /etc/cron.daily/backup

#!/bin/sh
rsync -avq /sourcedir1 /sourcedir2 user@yourlocalmachine.example.com:/destinationdir

~# chmod 755 /etc/cron.daily/backup
```

Test the command first on a live shell without the -q flag to check that everything works.  The cron job will run every night. You can put a similar script in /etc/cron.weekly and so on.

You can revert the whole process and set up the script/cronjob on your local machine, depending on your situation.